# How do I get past the libc dependency issues on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

How do I get past the libc dependency issues on 12.04

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"


sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1654 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,942 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,886 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
locales
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
libc6:i386 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.
Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
libc6 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.
Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
locales
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo apt-cache policy libc6 locales

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-12
  Candidate: 2.19-13
  Version table:
     2.19-13 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.19-12 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15-0ubuntu10.9 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-3
  Candidate: 2.19-13
  Version table:
     2.19-13 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.13+git20120306-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I have removed debian packages from this list.

```
sudo apt-cache policy libc6 locales
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-12
  Candidate: 2.19-12
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-12 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15-0ubuntu10.9 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-3
  Candidate: 2.13+git20120306-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.13+git20120306-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy libc6 locales` in your question.

Comment: @g_p I have attached the output of the above command

Comment: why you have added Debian package repository in your source list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is appearing because you have added Debian repository( i.e `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/...`) in your source list.

So first remove it from  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then execute following commands in terminal

- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -f`

It then should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -f
```

it will purge all the updates that you have done in the recent past

Comment: This worked for me